# Event to some dynamically generated checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

My english is not good but I need help please!!!

I am dynamically adding rows to a table, add textbox and checkbox's.

In the change function I want: When the first checkbox is marked the others are disabled and the texbox change their value

The updatebox function It works perfectly for each generated row, but change function only it works with the first.

```
function agregar() {
  var fila = $('<tr></tr>');
  var columna = $('<td></td>');
  var input = $('<input type="text" />').attr({
    name: 'idiomas_usu[]',
    id: 'list1'
  });
  columna.append(input);
  input = $('<input type="checkbox" />').attr({
    name: 'dos',
    class: 'cb2',
    id: 'cb2'
  });
  columna.append(input);
  input = $('<input type="text" />').attr({
    name: 'idiomas_usu[]',
    id: 'list2'
  });
  columna.append(input);
  input = $('<input type="checkbox" />').attr({
    name: 'dos',
    class: 'cb2',
    id: 'cb3'
  });
  columna.append(input);
  input = $('<input type="text" />').attr({
    name: 'idiomas_usu[]',
    id: 'list3'
  });
  columna.append(input);
  input = $('<input type="checkbox" />').attr({
    name: 'dos',
    class: 'cb2',
    id: 'cb4'
  });
  columna.append(input);
  input = $('<input type="text" />').attr({
    name: 'idiomas_usu[]',
    id: 'list4'
  });
  columna.append(input);
  input = $('<input type="checkbox" />').attr({
    name: 'dos',
    class: 'cb2',
    id: 'cb5'
  });
  columna.append(input);
  fila.append(columna);
  $('#tab_logic').append(fila);
}

function updateBox(event) {
  var input = $(this).prev();
  if (this.checked) {
    input.val("1");
  } else {
    input.val("");
  }
}

function change(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is("#cb2")) {
    if ($("#cb2:checked").length > 0) {
      $("#cb3").prop({
        disabled: true,
        checked: false
      });
      $("#cb4").prop({
        disabled: true,
        checked: false
      });
      $("#cb5").prop({
        disabled: true,
        checked: false
      });
      $("#list2").prop({
        disabled: true,
        value: ''
      });
      $("#list3").prop({
        disabled: true,
        value: ''
      });
      $("#list4").prop({
        disabled: true,
        value: ''
      });

    } else {
      $("#cb3").prop("disabled", false);
      $("#cb4").prop("disabled", false);
      $("#cb5").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  }
}

$('#boton').click(agregar);
$('#tab_logic').on('click', '.cb2', updateBox);
$('#tab_logic').on('click', '.cb2', change);
```

Here's the code running: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rko41z88/7/)

Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all the same IDs so its grabbing the first occurrence.  One option is to give your rows an ID and use that in your jQuery selector to target the correct items, like this: **https://jsfiddle.net/rko41z88/8/**

Below is a snippet of the fiddle, go to the fiddle to see the whole thing in action.

Give your rows an ID in your `agregar()` function like this...

```
window.myRowCnt = window.myRowCnt+1;
var fila = $('<tr id="row'+window.myRowCnt+'"></tr>');
```

Then use that row ID to target the correct items like this...

```
function change(event){
 var $this = $(this);
 var rowId = $this.closest('tr')[0].id;
    if ($this.is("#cb2")) {
        if ($("#"+rowId+" #cb2:checked").length > 0) {
            $("#"+rowId+" #cb3").prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
              $("#"+rowId+" #cb4").prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
                 $("#"+rowId+" #cb5").prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
                 $("#"+rowId+" #list2").prop({ disabled: true, value: '' });
                 $("#"+rowId+" #list3").prop({ disabled: true, value: '' });
                 $("#"+rowId+" #list4").prop({ disabled: true, value: '' });

        } else {
            $("#"+rowId+" #cb3").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#"+rowId+" #cb4").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#"+rowId+" #cb5").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: That's just what I needed :)

Comment: @pratikwebdev it works removing the property disabled: true of the checkboxes, I can send the form and capture their values

Answer (score -3):

This might not be the best answer for you, but I recommend to use React.js framework. It's best for dynamic web applications.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a very opinionated comment